# Tool to support user interface design reviews

Tags: software-development, user-interface

My software development team uses **[Kiln](http://www.fogcreek.com/kiln/)** for its [source control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control). We're really happy with its code reviews too (similar to [Gerrit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerrit_%28software%29) for Git), as they can happen asynchronously, are easily tracked with email notifications and have a clear review status (among other reasons). We're now looking for **something equivalent for reviewing screenshots of our user interfaces**.

Granted, no review process based on screenshots will allow us to review the *interactivity* as well as a live test would, but we still feel there's benefit to be had from reviewing such static images - especially if the tool were integrated with our task management or has its own built-in.

We've looked at lots of online tools ([Notable](http://www.notableapp.com/), [Marqueed](http://www.marqueed.com/), [InVision](http://www.invisionapp.com/), [GoVisually](http://www.govisually.com/), [Prevue](http://prevue.it/), [DesignDrop](http://www.designdrop.io/), etc. etc.), but have yet to find anything that has the right combination of features, would scale well to having hundreds of reviews over time and isn't riddled with bugs or usability issues.

**Can anyone recommend a "Kiln/Gerrit for UI reviews"?**

Key features we're looking for are:

- Each review can contain multiple screenshots
- Each review to have an owner (whose work is under review) and multiple reviewers
- Reviewers can mark [rectangular] areas of the screenshot and associate comments with them
- Anyone involved in the review is able to make and reply to comments
- Can attach an image to comments for illustrative purposes (non-essential)
- Each reviewer can set a review status (approved, needs work, etc.)
- Actions / tasks can be generated and tracked within the review (non-essential)
- Review owner can upload revisions, resetting the review status(es)
- Each revision has its own set of comments
- Email notifications can be sent when a comment is made, review status is changed, or a revision is uploaded
- Reviews can be given (and ordered/filtered by) metadata e.g. project, milestone, etc.

I realise that's a pretty long list, but I feel it's still pretty much the basics for a useful review system.

Comment: Be good to give a summary list of features; yes we can figure out what features you want/need from the body but if anyone that isn't familiar with Kiln may not know what features you want/need and certainly not what features your team places the highest importance too.

Comment: Good point - have now added a list of desired features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, we chose [Notism](http://www.notism.io/). As it stands (2014-09-10), it meets the majority of our requirements and is pretty stable (a problem with some of the other options). Specifically:

**It meets these requirements:**

- Each review can contain multiple screenshots
- Each review to have an owner (whose work is under review) and multiple reviewers
- Reviewers can mark [rectangular] areas of the screenshot and associate comments with them
- Anyone involved in the review is able to make and reply to comments
- Can attach an image to comments for illustrative purposes (non-essential)
- Actions / tasks can be generated and tracked within the review (non-essential)
- Review owner can upload revisions, resetting the review status(es)
- Each revision has its own set of comments

**It also partially meets the following requirements:**

- Each reviewer can set a review status (approved, needs work, etc.)

  - In fact, each screen in a review gets its own status and that status can't be set to different values for different reviewers (so John can't approve it if Belinda rejects it and vice versa)
- Email notifications can be sent when a comment is made, review status is changed, or a revision is uploaded

  - In fact, it doesn't (yet) send notifications of changes in review status (though the other notifications are sent)

**It doesn't meet this requirement:**

- Reviews can be given (and ordered/filtered by) metadata e.g. project, milestone, etc.

The review status stuff is probably my biggest issue with it, but all in all, I'm fairly pleased.

Answer (score 2):

Though I myself prefer Marqueed, [Concept inbox](http://conceptinbox.com/) matches your requirement better.

Let's get through your task list. After registering,

- Go to [the app homepage](https://app.conceptinbox.com/projects) and create a new project.
- Drop relevant pictures
- When you start feeling lonely, invite others to review your work. You can have multiple reviewers, and the creator will keep owning the project.
- You can circles areas you wish to comment, or draw directly on the picture.
- I don't believe you can attach pictures to your comments, but you can submit some as reviews.
- Four status exist: Work in Progress, Feedback needed, Waiting for approval, Completed.
- As I only use the free trial, I'm not sure whether anyone, or just the owner, can dedit status.
- Drop new pictures on top of the old to upload a revision.
- Only one revision can be displayed at a time to reviewers. If you wish to display them side by side and to choose comment, just name them rev 1, rev 2, so they stay independent one from another.

The tool fails short on your two last requirements. I'm far from certain it is the perfect tool for you, but given your requirements and other things you've tested, you should give it a try. Note that it has feature that allow you to recreate the UI of your project without coding for it to be reviewed as a whole and not only as individual print-screen.

Sorry for this messy review and hope it helps!

[image]

Comment: Although it might not be relevant I'm curious as to why you prefer Marqueed?

Comment: I don't have the same requirements as the author, and often this is less about what the tool does than how it does it. Marqueed suits my mind better.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I'll take a look.